# How can I input the special character ⇩ in Isabelle/jedit?

Tags: isabelle

In the Isabelle IDE jedit, I would like to input the following non-ascii symbol ⇩ which is used in locales/classes.

Despite many googling attempts, I could not manage to find how to do this (apart from copy-pasting the symbol). How do I input ⇩ ?

More generally, is there an easy way to find how to input a given symbol that I encounter in some Isabelle theory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally input ⇩ by typing `\sub` and when the autocomplete popup shows complete by pressing Tab. You can also find it and other symbols in the "Symbols" tab located by default at the bottom of jedit. ⇩ is found under the "Control" subtab there.

A list of all available symbols can be found in Appendix B of [The Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/isar-ref.pdf). The "input and autocomplete" method should work for all of these.

Comment: I use C-e downarrow, but the Symbols tab is the place to go.